# DELETE mysql statement using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am new to MYSQL and i am facing a very easy problem with MYSQL. I am creating a database that contains a student table , this table contains the student's name , ID( primary key) . I need to delete a record based on the user's choice of id ( call this variable student_id) , so how to write this in a mysql statement using python ? i have tried this but i know it is wrong -->

```
cur.execute("Delete FROM students WHERE ID = student_id")
```

Comment: What about it makes you say it is wrong?  What library are you using to communicate with your database?

Comment: After running query, you need to commit the changes using `con.commit()` where `con` is  your connection object

Comment: @ Scot Hunter i have used this  import mysql.connector , if that what you mean . @MoinuddinQuadri I have done so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
student_id = int(input('Please, enter an ID: '))  # In Python 3, you need to parse the user input for numbers.

statmt = "DELETE FROM `students` WHERE id = %s"
cur.execute(statmt, (student_id,))
conn.commit()  # You need to commit the transaction
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't worked for me , here is my code for deleting the record :  student_id=input('please enter ID')
 statmt="DELETE FROM student WHERE id = ?"
cur.execute(statmt,(student_id,))
 conn.commit()

Comment: Note the table name is student. Here is the error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed/PycharmProjects/DATABASE/Test2.py", line 42, in <module>
    cur.execute(statmt,(student_id,))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: You use which version of Python?

Comment: my python version is 3.4.0

Comment: So you need to use `student_id = int(input('please enter ID'))`. Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Done . Same error exist error: Please, enter an ID: 12345
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed/PycharmProjects/DATABASE/Test2.py", line 43, in <module>
    cur.execute(statmt, (student_id,))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 507, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I have got a new error after doing this.  raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Take a look at my edit, you need to use `%s` instead of `?`